# How do I store and send an image file using useState to the backend and then to my database in MERN stack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, multer, mern

I'm trying to add a form in which users can add text and images which is then going to be stored on the mongodb database. As of right now, I'm trying to add a section in the form where users can add images. This is the tutorial I'm following: https://www.tutsmake.com/file-upload-in-mongodb-using-node-js/

The tutorial uses this following piece of code to send the image to the backend:

```
<form action="/uploadphoto" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/*">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Photo">
    </form>
```

but I am not able to do that since I'm sending the other pieces of data I have using `useState` like so:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { adminSDGOptions } from "./AdminCategoryLists";
import { adminAssingmentOptions } from "./AdminCategoryLists";
import { keywordsOptions } from "../FilterComponents/CategoryArrays/KeywordsOptions";
import Multiselect from "multiselect-react-dropdown"
import Select from 'react-select';

const ProjectAdminForm = () => {
    // Adding basic info
    const [sdg, setSDG] = useState('')
    const [goal, setGoal] = useState('')
    const [orginization, setOrginization] = useState('')
    const [source, setSource] = useState('')
    const [location, setLocation] = useState('')
    const [published, setPublished] = useState('')
    const [website_url, setWebsiteURL] = useState('')
    const [assignment_type, setAssignmentType] = useState('')
    const [sharepoint_link, setSharepointLink] = useState('')
    const [statement, setStatement] = useState('')
    const [preview_img, setPreviewImg] = useState([])
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)

    // Adding keywords
    const [keywords, setKeywords] = useState([]);


    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault() // Prevents refresh of page from happening
        console.log('button clicked')

        const project = {sdg, goal, orginization, source, location, published, website_url, assignment_type, keywords, sharepoint_link, statement, preview_img}
        console.log(project)
            
        // Sending form response to backend
        const response = await fetch('/api/projects', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(project),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        const json = await response.json
        

        // Checking for error
        if (!response.ok) {
            setError(json.error)
        }
        if (response.ok) {
            // Reset form inputs back to empty string
            setSDG('')
            setGoal('')
            setOrginization('')
            setSource('')
            setLocation('')
            setPublished('')
            setWebsiteURL('')
            setAssignmentType('')
            setKeywords([])
            setSharepointLink('')
            setStatement('')
            
            setError(null)
            alert('Project added!')
            console.log('new project added', json)
        }
    }

    return (
        <form className="create project-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <h2 style={{"textAlign": "center"}}>Add a New Project</h2>

            <hr></hr>

            <label>Sustainable Development Goal:</label>
            <Select
                className="basic-single"
                classNamePrefix="select"
                placeholder="Select"
                name="color"
                options={adminSDGOptions}
                onChange={(selection) => setSDG(selection.value)}
                required
            />

            <label>Description:</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setGoal(e.target.value)}
                value={goal}
                required
            />

            <label>OPTIONAL - Organization:</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setOrginization(e.target.value)}
                value={orginization}
            />

            <label>OPTIONAL - Source:</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setSource(e.target.value)}
                value={source}
            />

            <label>OPTIONAL - Location:</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}
                value={location}
            />

            <label>Published (YEAR ONLY):</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setPublished(e.target.value)}
                value={published}
                required
            />

            <label>OPTIONAL - Website URL:</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setWebsiteURL(e.target.value)}
                value={website_url}
            />

            <label>Assignment Type:</label>
            <Select
                className="basic-single"
                classNamePrefix="select"
                placeholder="Select"
                name="color"
                options={adminAssingmentOptions}
                onChange={(selection) => setAssignmentType(selection.value)}
                required
            />

            <hr></hr>

            <label>Enter Keyword(s):</label>
            <Multiselect
                className="multiselect-admin"
                isObject={false}
                onRemove={(selection) => setKeywords(selection)}
                onSelect={(selection) => setKeywords(selection)}
                options={keywordsOptions}
                required
            />

            <hr></hr>

            <label>OPTIONAL - Statement (ONLY Assessment Ideas and Discussion Topics):</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setStatement(e.target.value)}
                value={statement}
            />

            <label>OPTIONAL - Qualtrics Link (ONLY Mini Case Study):</label>
            <input 
                type="text"
                onChange={(e) => setSharepointLink(e.target.value)}
                value={sharepoint_link}
            />
            
            // THIS IS THE SECTION I'M TRYING TO ADD AND AM NOT SURE HOW TO GO ABOUT DOING SO
            <label>OPTIONAL - Preview image:</label>
            <input
                type="file"
                name="preview_img"
                accept="image/*"
                onChange={(e) => setPreviewImg(e.target.value)}
            />
            
            <div className="add-proj">
                <button>Add Project</button>
            </div>
            
            {error && <div className="error">{error}</div>}
        </form>
    )
}

export default ProjectAdminForm
```

Right now, when I try uploading a file and sending it, it is just getting sent as a String called this:

```
preview_img: "C:\\fakepath\\banner2 (2).jpg"
```

Does anyone know how I can upload a file using `useState` similar to how I uploaded the other pieces of Strings in the form above to my Node backend which then gets uploaded to the database?

This is what my model looks like:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose') 

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

// Project schematic
const projectSchema = new Schema({
    // general schema templates

    // sdg
    sdg: [{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }],
    // description of the project
    goal: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    orginization: {
        type: String,
    },
    source: {
        type: String,
    },
    location: {
        type: String,
    },
    // year published
    published: { 
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    website_url: {
        type: String,
    },
    assignment_type: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    // array of keywords
    keywords: [{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }],

    // assignment specific schema templates
    // ONLY APPLIES TO TIER 1 ASSIGNMENTS, NOT REQUIRED
    statement: {
        type: String
    },

    // ONLY APPLIES TO TIER 2 ASSIGNMENTS, NOT REQUIRED
    sharepoint_link: {
        type: String
    },

    preview_img: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    }
    
}, { timestamps: true })

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema)
```

I need a way to somehow upload a file in this portion of my project controller file:

```
// create new project
const createProject = async (req, res) => {
    const {sdg, goal, orginization, source, location, published, website_url, assignment_type, keywords, sharepoint_link, statement, preview_img} = req.body
    const newProject = new Project({
        sdg: sdg,
        goal : goal,
        orginization : orginization,
        source : source,
        location : location,
        published : published,
        website_url : website_url,
        assignment_type : assignment_type,
        keywords: keywords,
        sharepoint_link : sharepoint_link,
        statement : statement,
        preview_img : preview_img
    });
    try {
        await newProject.save();
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(400).json({error: error.message})

    }
   
    return res.status(201).json({project: newProject});
}
```

Does anyone know how I can go about doing this?

Comment: Can you reduce code snippet to minimal required to describe the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use formData for this in react:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("sdg", sdg);
formData.append("goal", goal);
formData.append("orginization", orginization);
formData.append("source", source);
formData.append("location", location);
formData.append("published", published);
formData.append("website_url", website_url);
formData.append("assignment_type", assignment_type);
formData.append("keywords", keywords);
formData.append("sharepoint_link", sharepoint_link);
formData.append("statement", statement);
formData.append("preview_img", preview_img);
```

and then pass this `formData` in your request body

Comment: Is the way I stored the image in my useState correct? I think the main issue with this right now is I don't know how to store an image using useState

Comment: If you are ok to use antd components then you can switch to it. It will make your work easy. https://ant.design/components/upload/